# Your app is built with a beta version of Xcode or iOS SDK

Tags: ios8, app-store-connect, xcode6gm

I am trying to submit my app to iTunes Connect compiled with Xcode 6.1 GM seed 2, which I believe is the public release. Base SDK is set to "Latest iOS (iOS 8.1) and deployment target is 7.0. But, when I submitted my build using Application loader it gave me this error.

"Your app is built with a beta version of Xcode or iOS SDK. Only apps distributed for beta testing may be built with beta software. To submit an app for distribution on the App Store, you will need to build the app with release versions of Xcode and iOS SDK."

Can anyone help!

Comment: I think you're a little ahead of the official releases.  Try the versions that are available from the store or iTunes: Xcode 6.0.1 and iOS 8.0.2.

Comment: "GM seed 2" is a clue here.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 6.1 is not yet available as a final release, as evidenced by [this page](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/) on Apple's website, which says that the 6.1 version of Xcode will be "available shortly."

The final release of Xcode 6.1 will include the final version of the iOS 8.1 SDK and will allow you to submit apps to the App Store that are built for that version of the SDK.

Since iOS 8.1 will be released on Monday, it is likely that it will be released sometime before then.

[image: Available Shortly]